# Spring Security + LDAP throws Bad credentials error when SSL/TLS enabled, but credentials are correct

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, ssl, spring-security, spring-ldap

I am using Spring Security, Spring LDAP & Spring boot in a web application.

Authentication was **working fine till** I enabled SSL/TSL using ldap**s**.

**What I did to enable SSL:**

1. Received Root + Intermediate CA certificates from security team and added below VM arguments when run this application.

   `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=<path to keystore> 
   -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=pass 
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path to keystore, same as above> 
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pass`

2.Changed ldap url to ldap**s**

3.Changed ldap port from 3268 to 636

4. Override default authentication statregy as below

   `LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
   AbstractTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy statregy = new DefaultTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy();
   statregy.setShutdownTlsGracefully(true);
   contextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(statregy);`

Even I use correct credentials, I am getting below error.
Please note, **same** credentials are working fine **without** SSL.

[image]

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Could you please check the LDAP response code on LDAP server side? Does it show LDAP error '49' (invalid credentials)?