# Spring Boot - Bad credentials when moving to SSL with JDBC authentification

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, ssl, spring-security

Like said in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861220/spring-security-ldap-throws-bad-credentials-error-when-ssl-tls-enabled-but-cr), when I tried to move from basic auth to SSL, I had a Bad Credentials response.

The only difference is that I'm using a database to store the credentials.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the issue was from a line I added in my SecurityConfiguration class (In a spring security context).

I read it from a tutorial but it wasn't necessary for what I was trying to do.

This line is :

```java
http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
```

Comment: Next time you ask remember to post the code with your question.